# @testable analogue in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, unit-testing

I want to write unit tests in Objective-C for my framework, which is written in swift. Is there a way to access internal API of framework from Objective-C tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a class `Foo` and you want to use internal API, e.g. method `- (void) bar;` you can just create an extension header `Foo+ExposePrivate.h` in your tests (no need to create implementation `Foo+ExposePrivate.m`) and import it where it's needed:

```
#import "Foo.h"

@interface Foo(ExposePrivate)

- (void) bar;

@end
```

If your class `Foo` is internal itself, add duplicating class declaration:

```
@interface Foo: SomeFooBase<SomeFooProtocol>
@end

@interface Foo(ExposePrivate)

- (void) bar;

@end
```

Comment: And what if class Foo itself is internal?

Comment: @user3237732 check the edit — just add the declaration of internal class